# background image reloading on hover?

Tags: css

I'm trying to make the background color change on :hover but keep the background image the same — the problem I'm having is that every "first time" it's hovered over after the page is loaded, the background image reloads, making it disappear and reappear for a split second. Of course, every other time you hover over the div after that it's fine, but it's always that first hover after the page is loaded that the div decides to not realize that it's using the same exact background on hover and reloads the same image again.

```
    #ask, #drop {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.38) url('example.png') no-repeat;
        width: 18px;
        height: 18px;
    }

    #ask:hover, #drop:hover {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.32);
    }

    #ask {
        background-position: 1px 1px;    
    }

    #drop {
        background-position: -300px 0px;
    }
```

Please keep in mind I'm not exactly sure if it's reloading or if it's just a browser bug or something.

Comment: Try ? `#example:hover {
    background: #666;
}`

Comment: you can just change the color only on hover no need to call the image again

Comment: I tried to make my example simple but I left out some aspects that might be affecting it so I'll update the question with all of the code.

Comment: `background` is shorthand for ALL styles and will wipe more specific `background-*` styles. Don't declare your background color with the shorthand. Use `background-color`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing the entire `background` when you only want to change `background-color`

use this:

```
#example:hover {
    background-color: #666;
}
```

Comment: I tried to make my example simple but I left out some aspects that might be affecting it so I'll update the question with all of the code.

Comment: Answer still stands. See my comments in your question.